# How to delete a picture after i searched it in database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

As an administrator i want to delete pictures from my website after i have searched the picture. But it doesn't delete the file ($target).

```
<nav>
    <a href="../Home/frontEnd.php"><img class="icon" src="../Logo/Home.png" /></a>
    <a href="../Search/search.php"><img class="icon" src="../Logo/Search.png" /></a>
    <a href="../Upload/upload.php"><img class="icon" src="../Logo/Camera.png" /></a>
    <a href="../Super/supervisor.php"><img class="icon" src="../Logo/Supervisor.png" /></a>
    <a href="../Profile/profile.php"><img class="icon" src="../Logo/Profile.png" /></a>
</nav>

<div class="searchDiv">
    <form action="supervisor.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="search" name="search" placeholder="Zoek een foto..." autocomplete="off">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitUpload" value="Zoeken">
    </form>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', '22894_opdracht1', '22894_opdracht1', '22894_database') or die ('Error connecting!');
$search = $_POST['search'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM instaclone WHERE description LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR username LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR date LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $target = $row['target'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    echo '<div class="picture">';
    echo '<div class="name">';
    echo '<div class="date">';
    echo $username . '<br>';
    echo $date;
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<img class="pictureShow" src="' . $target . '" /><br>';
    echo '<p class="beschrijving">' . '<b>' . $username  . ': </b>' . $description;
    echo '<div class="reactions">';
    echo '<form method="post">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="reaction" class="reaction" placeholder="Een reactie toevoegen...">';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

        if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM instaclone WHERE target LIKE  '%" . $target . "%' ";
        }
    }
mysqli_close($dbc);
}
?>

<div class="deleteDiv">
    <form action="supervisor.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="delete" id="submitUpload" value="Delete">
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to delete $target after the delete sumbit button is pressed.

Comment: The delete if (`if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {`) is inside the submit if (`if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {`) but you are not submiting the two inputs at the same time

Comment: within this method, you will delete only the url of this image, this url is the part that connect the html to host folder of pictures.

Comment: You need to clean your db params to prevent sql injections, also I suggest to use PDO with bind parmas

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM instaclone WHERE target = '$target' ";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
        echo "$target deleted";

    }
```

Comment: I moved the `if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {}` out of the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` , but the variable target is now undefined, do i have to fetch $result again?

And i closed the $dbc before the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`